# How to automate or quickly set table style (cell background paint) in Cytoscape by amino acid type?

Tags: java, bioinformatics, cytoscape

I am visualizing a network of related peptide sequences in Cytoscape. The amino acid sequence is split into columns (i.e. Col1: amino acid 1, Col2, amino acid 2, Col3: amino acid 3, etc), and I want to color the background of the cell in the table based on the amino acid type (i.e. aromatic F,Y,W = color1, basic H,K,R = color2, acidic D,E = color3, etc.) so that I can quickly see amino acids that share chemical properties. I can do this manually through the 'Table' tab in the style window by setting the Cell Background Paint and discretely mapping each amino acid to a color for each column, but this is quite laborious (see image below).

In short, I want help to do all this 'Table' style formatting at once in an automated fashion.

[Screenshot of cytoscape 'Table' style window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmNp3.jpg)

My attempts to address this issue have failed: (1) The 'Table' tab style cannot be exported so I can't set the color scheme and then import it to other cytoscape networks. (2) The developers of py4cytoscape did not include options for setting the 'Table' tab styles (only for Node, Edge, and Network styles). (3) The only mention of 'Cell Background Paint' in any kind of scripting context is in documentation for Cytoscape App Developers or API specification for Cytoscape using a Java Swing front-end which is a little too complicated for me currently so I would like help in finding a way to quickly set the Table style in an automated way.

Answer (score 0):

Table styles are pretty new, so not everything is there yet.  Cytoscape 3.10 (which is coming out soon) will integrate Table Styles into styles in a more general way, which will include the ability to export and import styles.  Not sure if py4cytoscape or RCy3 have added interfaces to Table Styles, but I'm sure it's coming.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question...

I also found that opening a cytoscape session file (archive) with 7zip gives access to the underlying data and settings and ultimately allowed me to more quickly set the Table Style. After playing around with it, there seems to be two key aspects to do this: (1) in the 'cytables.xml' file, there must be a styleTitle for each columnName to be styled and (2) the same styleTitle must be used for same column in the 'session_vizmap.xml' file and this is where the style is actually set. It is easiest to manually set the style in cytoscape and then use it as an example/guide if anyone else has this same issue and wants a partial solution.

In practice, I now manually set one amino acid to one color in every column in cytoscape and then save the session. This generates the styleTitle and sets the discrete mapping in the xml files so all I have to do is copy and paste my list of <discreteMappingEntry attributeValue="aminoacid" value="color" /> for each column in the session_vizmap.xml file. It is not the most elegant but I can do it in <5 min with much less clicking now.